# Double Your Bitcoin In 24 Hours is it possible or true?

Tags: bitcoin-xt

is double your bitcoin in 24 hours company is legit company? actually i am using continue to invest on it and each time they provide me payout but my question is this

1. is this is a legit system?
2. is they regular provide me payout?
3. can i invest a hug amount on it?

Thanks 
this is url: https://www.doublebitcoin24hours.com/

Comment: Apply some common sense and skepticism:  Do you honestly *believe* it is *possible* to consistently, reliably double your money overnight?  Where would that new money come from? What would the consequence if many people did that? How many days would it take for someone to become a billionaire?

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly a scam and not a very good one at that. The website design and English grammar on the website is appalling. It looks like it was outsourced via upwork.com with a $10 budget. At least they are honest about the quality of the English grammar on the website as seen by the Html lang="zxx" tag in the page source; which basically translates as 'the text is known to be not in any language'.

It seems to be a lead generator for naive / stupid 'investors' who have no real understanding of bitcoin / crypto.

I imagine that the stupid investor sends bitcoin and gets nothing in return. When the investor gets annoyed, s/he gets quoted the psuedo English  disclaimer: '*In no event shall multiply bitcoins legit be liable for any special, direct, indirect, consequential, or incidental damages or any damages whatsoever, whether in an action of contract, negligence or other tort, arising out of or in connection with the use of the Service or the contents of the Service*'.

To test this hypothesis, we could analyse the bitcoin address that investors send to on blockchain.info.

Assuming that the company behind the website is indeed 'Bitcoin Block Ltd', then according to duedil.com (aggregates data from Companies House), the proud owner of this company is one Taylor Wilkinson: https://www.duedil.com/company/gb/10825300/bitcoin-block-limited/directors.

If Bitcoin Block Ltd is indeed behind this website (can't tell for sure as the website WHOIS is private and could be leaching onto a legit UK company name for social proof), then wow - there must be a lot of mugs in this world since the 'business' must be paying for the costs of a virtual office in Mayfair (registered address).

Answer (score 1):

sites like this are always scam. you *can* double your assets when you exchange your bitcoins in (mostly unknown) altcoins which have increasing charts in the next 24h. but no **one can warranty that this works in your case**. it *can* work: look at [this](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/paccoin/) or [this](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/campuscoin/) or [this](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/tittiecoin/) or [this](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/rimbit/) chart. and there are several more charts likes these where the value of 1 coin increases tenfold in a few days. nevertheless it is difficult to double your assets because this doublings occurs only a few times (if ever) and you do not know which coins will increase. there are more coins which will not increase, and this prediction ("which coin will double and which not?") is a *very* risky guesswork.